# Form filled out but still invalid

Tags: django

I am trying to get data from a form and redirect if the form is valid. I am, however, seemingly not grabbing any data. In a test, I fill out each form with "test". I would expect these forms to be valid and redirect to a success page, and am unable to figure out where I am going wrong with my logic.

Error:

```
form.errors = <ul class="errorlist"><li>category<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>comment<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class CandidateReportForm(forms.Form):
    category = forms.CharField(label='Category', max_length=10)
    comment = forms.CharField(label='Comment', max_length=1000)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

from .forms import CandidateReportForm


class CandidateReportView(View):
    form_class = CandidateReportForm
    form_template = 'Reports/candidate_report.html'
    form_submit_template = 'Reports/report_submitted.html'
    form_submit_error = 'Reports/report_error.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.form_template, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, self.form_submit_template)
        else:
            print(f"form.errors = {form.errors}")
            return render(request, self.form_submit_error)
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <h2 class="card-title">Report</h2>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <form action="submit_candidate_report" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" id="report" name="report" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering your form **outside** the `form` tag! Only fields inside the `form` tag are submitted to the server, so your html for the `form` tag should be:

```
<form action="submit_candidate_report" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" id="report" name="report" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```